# Remain, Hide and reset select option based on button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

sorry the title was kind of confusing.

I would like to hide these select options and just be displayed when the user chooses a button.
Once the user chooses a button, I would like the select field will remain to be displayed...
But if the user chooses a different button, I would like to reset the selected options from the previous choice and shows off.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(':radio').on('change', function() {
    var title = $(this).val(); // Get radio value
    if ($(this).attr('id') === 'theme2') {
      $('.occ_select').addClass('l').removeClass('off');
    } else { //...otherwise status of radio is off
      $('.occ_select').removeClass('l').addClass('off');
    }

    $("#occa_slct option").eq(0).prop("selected", title == "dedi") //set to first option when value of title is dedi
    $("#occa_slct").prop("disabled", title == "dedi") //disable select when value of title is dedi
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(':radio').on('change', function() {
    var title = $(this).val();
    if ($(this).attr('id') === 'shape1') {
      $('.c_select').addClass('l').removeClass('off');
    } else {
      $('.c_select').removeClass('l').addClass('off');
    }

    $("#c_slct option").eq(0).prop("selected", title == "heart")
    $("c_slct").prop("disabled", title == "heart")
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(':radio').on('change', function() {
    var title = $(this).val();
    if ($(this).attr('id') === 'shape2') {
      $('.h_select').addClass('l').removeClass('off');
    } else {
      $('.h_select').removeClass('l').addClass('off');
    }

    $("#h_slct option").eq(0).prop("selected", title == "circle")
    $("h_slct").prop("disabled", title == "circle") 
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<hr>
Choose Theme:
<br> <input type="radio" id="theme1" name="cake_theme" value="dedi" /> Dedication
<br> <input type="radio" id="theme2" name="cake_theme" value="occ" /> Others


<div id="occassion" class="occ_select off">
  <select name="occassion_select" id="occa_slct">
     <option disabled selected value>-- Select one --</option>
     <option value="otheerrr"> otheerrr </option>
     <option value="other1"> other1 </option>
     <option value="other2"> other2 </option>
 </select>
</div>
<hr>

Choose Shape:
<br> <input type="radio" id="shape1" name="shape" value="circle" /> Circle

 <div id="circle" class="circle_select off">
  <select name="c_select" id="c_slct">
     <option disabled selected value>-- Select one --</option>
     <option value="big"> big </option>
     <option value="med"> med </option>
     <option value="small"> small </option>
 </select>
</div>

<br> <input type="radio" id="shape2" name="shape" value="heart" /> Heart

 <div id="heart" class="heart_select off">
  <select name="h_select" id="h_slct">
     <option disabled selected value>-- Select one --</option>
     <option value="big"> big </option>
     <option value="med"> med </option>
     <option value="small"> small </option>
 </select>
</div>

<hr>
```

As you can see, there's a bug happening or confusion going on. 
Please ask me if you need clarification of what am I trying to say.
Hope somebody can help me out.
THANK YOU IN ADVANCE!!

Comment: Your question is a little unclear. For example, what to show when Dedication is clicked? Do you want any value in the selectbox to be selected once the checkbox is clicked? If the user chooses a different checkbox, do you want the last one's selectbox to be hidden? etc,etc...

Comment: Sorry for that. I want all the "select fields" will be hidden at first. I want to trigger the radio button to show up. e.g. the button others, when i choose others the select field will be displayed. And when I choose the Dedication the others select will be disappeared and resets its selection.

Comment: what the "off" class do? include the css too

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for.

- On radio button change function check whether selected radio button belongs to choose theme or shape using name attribute.
- If it's choose shape, then check whether its shape1 or shape2.
- If it's shape1 then set display prop of shape1 select box(#c_select) to block and shape2 select box(#h_select) to none and vice versa. And reset #h_select default selection. Same method for choose theme radio buttons
- Now if you want, on document ready set default value for all select box using $("selector").each function.

NOTE: you don't have to put every logic in separate document ready function (see [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself))

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select").each (function() {
    $(this).find ('option:eq(1)').prop('selected', true); 
  });
  $(':radio').on('change', function() {
    var title = $(this).val(); // Get radio value
    if ($(this).attr ("name") === "cake_theme") {
      if ($(this).attr('id') === 'theme2') {
        $('.occ_select').css ({"display": "block"});
      } 
      else if ($(this).attr('id') === 'theme1') { 
        $('.occ_select').css ({"display": "none"});
        $('.occ_select option:eq(1)').prop('selected', true);
      } 
    }
    else if ($(this).attr ("name") === "shape") {
      if ($(this).attr('id') === 'shape1') {
        $('#c_slct').css ({"display": "block"});
        $('#h_slct').css ({"display": "none"});
        $('#h_slct option:eq(1)').prop('selected', true);
      } 
      else if ($(this).attr('id') === 'shape2') {
        $('#c_slct').css ({"display": "none"});
        $('#c_slct option:eq(1)').prop('selected', true);
        $('#h_slct').css ({"display": "block"});
      } 
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<hr>
Choose Theme:
<br> <input type="radio" id="theme1" name="cake_theme" value="dedi" /> Dedication
<br> <input type="radio" id="theme2" name="cake_theme" value="occ" /> Others


<div id="occassion" class="occ_select off">
  <select name="occassion_select" id="occa_slct">
     <option disabled selected value>-- Select one --</option>
     <option value="otheerrr"> otheerrr </option>
     <option value="other1"> other1 </option>
     <option value="other2"> other2 </option>
 </select>
</div>
<hr>

Choose Shape:
<br> <input type="radio" id="shape1" name="shape" value="circle" /> Circle

 <div id="circle" class="circle_select off">
  <select name="c_select" id="c_slct">
     <option disabled selected value>-- Select one --</option>
     <option value="big"> big </option>
     <option value="med"> med </option>
     <option value="small"> small </option>
 </select>
</div>

<br> <input type="radio" id="shape2" name="shape" value="heart" /> Heart

 <div id="heart" class="heart_select off">
  <select name="h_select" id="h_slct">
     <option disabled selected value>-- Select one --</option>
     <option value="big"> big </option>
     <option value="med"> med </option>
     <option value="small"> small </option>
 </select>
</div>

<hr>
```